# Profit formula stress test

Tags: stress-testing

〖Profit(d)〗_is= f_s (〖Turnover〗_i )-c_s (〖costs〗_i)
=(1+f(k_s ┤| p_s,q_s))*〖turnover〗_i-[(1+g_s )*〖energycosts〗_i]*(1+h)*(1+ e_e*f(k_s | q_s))-(1+ e_l*f(k_s | q_s))* 〖wage costs〗_i-(1+e_o*f((k_s | q_s )) * 〖other costs〗_i

Where : (1 + (|, )) = (1 + ) ∗ (1 + ) and  =  ∗ [(1 + ) ∗ energycosts] ∗ (1 + ℎ)

I need to input this formula in python to calculate profit in case where there is a shock to energycosts g_s. This shock also impacts turnover as firms would increase their prices by passing a part of this onto the consumer which is . The eventual price change ps is then also altered due to energy saving measures ℎ. What i dont understand is how the price change is then a number in euros and you fill this in in (1 + (|, )) = (1 + ) ∗ (1 + ). Then this is multiplied with turnover but would generate a huge amount which is not the intention. Following my idea is that turnover should be increased with a percentage and not multiplied with a number in euros. But energycosts is a cashflow value. Can somebody help me figure out how this formula works?

For this case i didnt consider other costs to make formula less complicated, but would add it if finding p and implementation of fpq works

def calculate_profit(omzet, energiekosten, loonkosten, d, q, g, h, e_e, e_l):
p = d * (1 + h) * (((1 + g) * energiekosten)
fpq = (1 + p) * (1 + q) - 1
winst = (1 + fpq) * omzet - (1 + g) * energiekosten * (1 + h) * (1 + e_e * q) - (1 + e_l * q) * loonkosten
return winst

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).